# Check for specific attribute/check for staleness of an element in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, ui-testing, puppeteer

Hi I am a little new to this, but I am in the process of moving over from Selenium with Node.js over to Puppeteer for UI testing, I wanted to know what would be the best way to check in Puppeteer if an element has become stale (removed from the DOM) and also the best way to check for a change in an element specific attribute (e.g. if an element's opacity has changed from 0 to 1 or an element has become disabled)

Here are some examples of how I used to achieve the two in Selenium:

Check for attribute change -

```
function waitForOpacity(driver, obj, time) {
  driver.wait(() => {
    return obj.getCssValue('opacity').then(opacity => opacity === '1')
  }, time)
} 

waitForOpacity(driver, submitButton, 30000)
submitButton.click()
```

Check for staleness of an element -

```
function stalenessOf(driver, until, obj, time) {
 return driver.wait(until.stalenessOf(obj), time)
}

stalenessOf(driver, until, someModalElement, 60000)
```

I have tried something like this in Puppeteer -

```
await page.waitForSelector('.myButton');
  await page.evaluate(() => {
    document.querySelector('.myButton').style.opacity === '1';
  }); 
  await page.click('.myButton');
```

However I don't think this is the right syntax...any help is appreciated, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out after some research, but not sure if it is the cleanest solution -

Checking for opacity change -

```
await page.waitForSelector('.myBtn');
  await page.waitFor(
    () => document.querySelector('.myBtn').style.opacity === '1'
  );
  await page.click('.myBtn');
```

Check for staleness of element -

```
await page.waitFor(
    () => !document.querySelector('.someModalElement')
  );
```